# JQuery datepicker default date and multiple datepickers

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Im using this datepicker
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

I have 2 date fields in the same html form.
I need the first field to load today as default date.
Second one as todays date -7 (1 week ago.)

Cant get this working for some reason. 
I can get both fields working but they wont load any default dates.

Any help is appreciated.

---

```
 $(function() {   
       $( "#from" ).datepicker({   
      defaultDate: "+1w",  
      changeMonth: true,   
      numberOfMonths: 1,  
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {  
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );  
      }  
    });  
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });  
  });  

Start date: <input type="text" id="from" name="from"> 
End date: <input type="text" id="to" name = "to">
```

Comment: Update your question and add the code that you have.

Comment: To confirm, the Start Date should be Today, and the End Date should be 1 week prior (or 7 days before).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make use of the `setDate` method. See More: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

> Sets the date for the datepicker. The new date may be a `Date` object or a string in the current date format (e.g., `"01/26/2009"`), a number of days from today (e.g., `+7`) or a string of values and periods (`"y"` for years, `"m"` for months, `"w"` for weeks, `"d"` for days, e.g., `"+1m +7d"`), or null to clear the selected date.

```js
$(function() {
  // Initialize Date Fields
  var from = $("#from").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });
  var to = $("#to").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });
  // Set Dates
  from.datepicker("setDate", "+0d");
  to.datepicker("setDate", "-7d");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Start date: <input type="text" id="from" name="from"> End date: <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```